# Azure service bus for publishing events

Tags: azure, queue, load-balancing, azureservicebus

We are making a multi-tenant system that should generate lots of events in bursts (especially during on boarding of new customers) and are looking for a way to decouple the event source with the event handlers. At first the azure service-bus with several subscriptions seemed to be the best case, but reading the limitations that seems to be limited in size. (like a few GB per topic), and even queue's are in my opinion still to small for our requirements. (About 80GB)

Don't get me wrong, we are not planning to ingest 100GB of data during normal operations (aka 99% of the time). However, considering that this is multi-tenant, the number of tenants (and therefore data/events) is bound to grow. And we prefer to use a single service-bus/queue in order to spread the load of all tenants between all our own servers. The nature of the event burst is so that a single tenant could generate huge burst of events, while the others aren't doing much; so creating a queue per tenant; and have each of our servers listen to a few tenant queue's is not really a good use of our hardware. And having all servers listen to all (many) queue's is probably also not a good way of load balancing.

So our most important requirements are:

- not ever miss any input.
- evenly spread the load across a variable number of servers. 
  (will ideally be scaled dynamically based on the size of the queue.)

But we can live with following drawbacks:

- it takes some time (days ...) before we have processed everything
- pay per GB actually used (compared to pay for a reservation)
- it slows down when you put to much data in.

Can this be done with Azure service bus / queue's?
Or any other Azure storage system?
Or do we need to look to something else entirely?

Comment: Have you looked at [Azure Event Grid](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/event-grid/)?

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of Azure Event Grids to solve meet your business requirement. You can send the events from different tenants to a an event grid topic.
The Event grid topic can be subscribed by multiple event subscriptions each configured with different endpoints which will process the events. The endpoint can be an Azure Function which will process the events from different tenants there by the load is evenly distributed.

You can use the filters of Event Grid Subscriptions to filter the events and distribute the load.

The Azure functions use Fan out pattern. So the load will be automatically handled by the function app and you will be costed only when there are events to the event grid.

[image: This architecture might serve your requirement]

Answer (score 0):

There is never a guarantee that an orchestration medium can be trusted for integrity 100% of the time. It's less about which orchestration medium to choose and more about designing pieces of the system in such a way that if something goes wrong, system can continue to be available while recovering without losing data.

You can consider different ways to ensure not ever losing input. For example as part of the process that accepts input, persisting received input into a near linearly scalable storage such as a [blob store](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-scalability-targets) and place a tiny message in a Azure Service Bus namespace containing just the message id (these two operations within a transaction). Then have another scalable unit (for example an azure logic app or function app) to place the complete payload into another azure service bus namespace. This way even if the second namespace reaches a max in size, first namespace would be continueing to collect new input, due to data in messages for the first namespace is very small. If this is also not scalable enough, there are many other ways to think about all coming with pro's and con's.